# How to add axis labels to imshow plots in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-visualization, axis-labels

I copied from [this website](https://glowingpython.blogspot.com/2012/01/how-to-plot-two-variable-functions-with.html) (and simplified) the following code to plot the result of a function with two variables using `imshow`.

```
from numpy import exp,arange
from pylab import meshgrid,cm,imshow,contour,clabel,colorbar,axis,title,show

# the function that I'm going to plot
def z_func(x,y):
return (x+y**2)

x = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
y = arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
X,Y = meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
Z = z_func(X, Y) # evaluation of the function on the grid

im = imshow(Z,cmap=cm.RdBu) # drawing the function

colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
show()
```

[image: Plot without axis labels]

How do I add axis labels (like `'x'` and `'y'` or `'var1` and `'var2'`) to the plot? In R I would use `xlab = 'x'` within (most of) the plotting function(s).

I tried [im.ylabel('y')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27671748/how-to-print-y-axis-label-horizontally-in-a-matplotlib-pylab-chart) with the

> AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'ylabel'

Beside this, I only found [how to remove the axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9295026/matplotlib-plots-removing-axis-legends-and-white-spaces), but not how to add them.

Bonus question: how to have the ticks range from `-3` to `3` and not from `0` to `60`?

Comment: Maybe you can try : `set_xlabel()` and `set_ylabel()`
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_xlabel.html
https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel.html

Comment: I don't think `pylab` is recommended anymore, `pyplot` should be used instead - see [this Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469336/what-is-the-difference-between-pylab-and-pyplot). If you insist on pylab you can always add `ylabel` and `xlabel` to your list of imports, `from pylab import ylabel`; `ylabel("y axis")`

Comment: @Jona `im.set_xlabel('x')` gives a similar error: `AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specify axes labels:

- [`matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xlabel.html) for the `x` axis
- [`matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ylabel.html) for the `y` axis

Regarding your bonus question, consider [`extent` kwarg](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/intermediate/imshow_extent.html). (Thanks to @Jona).

Moreover, consider absolute imports as recommended by [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

> Absolute imports are recommended, as they are usually more readable
>   and tend to be better behaved (or at least give better error messages)
>   if the import system is incorrectly configured (such as when a
>   directory inside a package ends up on sys.path)

---

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# the function that I'm going to plot
def z_func(x,y):
    return (x+y**2)

x = np.arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
y = np.arange(-3.0,3.0,0.1)
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x, y) # grid of point
Z = z_func(X, Y) # evaluation of the function on the grid

plt.xlabel('x axis')
plt.ylabel('y axis')

im = plt.imshow(Z,cmap=plt.cm.RdBu, extent=[-3, 3, -3, 3]) # drawing the function

plt.colorbar(im) # adding the colobar on the right
plt.show()
```

and you get:

[image]