# Passing optional arguments to, e.g., ax.set(ylabel=...)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Having read this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27671748/2749397) I know how I can specify optional arguments to a *y* label object, using either the `pyplot` namespace

```
plt.ylabel('y', rotation='horizontal', ha='right')
```

or the object oriented one

```
ax.set_ylabel(...)
```

but I don't know how I could possibly use the convenient syntax

```
ax.set(ylabel=???)
```

and still be able to specify additional parameters.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "*still be able to specify additional parameters*"? `ax.set()` accepts multiple parameters, as I surmise you know

Comment: @WilliamMiller I'd like to say e.g. `ax.set(ylabel=dict(text='y', ha='right', fonstsize=13))` but that does not work, so I'm here, asking if there is a way of tricking `ax.set` to do what I want...

Comment: You may want to consider including that piece of code in the question body - it is very helpful in clarifying exactly what it is you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Axes` class doesn't have an override for the `set()` method, so `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set()` is the same as [`matplotlib.artist.Artist.set()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L1086) which [calls `matplotlib.artist.Artist.update()`](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L1113) with the the specified keyword argument list (`props`). `update()` looks like [this](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L972):

```py
def update(self, props):
    ret = []
    with cbook._setattr_cm(self, eventson=False):
        for k, v in props.items():
            # ...
            if k == "axes":
                ret.append(setattr(self, k, v))
            else:
                func = getattr(self, f"set_{k}", None)
                if not callable(func):
                    raise AttributeError(f"{type(self).__name__!r} object "
                                         f"has no property {k!r}")
                ret.append(func(v))
    # ....
    return ret
```

This goes through the `props` dict and checks if a setter method of `self` (in the case of `matplotlib.axes.Axes.set()` the `Axes` instance) exists for each key, if it does then it calls it with the associated value, if not it raises an `AttributeError`. This means that you can't use the `set()` method to change attributes for which there is no defined setter method (the one exception is that you can pass the `axes` argument to reset the axes).

Since `matplotlib.axes.Axes` does not have a setter for the label rotations and alignments, you can't use `ax.set()` to mutate these. What you *can* do is call `.set()` on the text instance instead, i.e.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
ylab = ax.set_ylabel("y-label")
ylab.set(rotation="horizontal", ha="right")
```

I think this is the closest to your desired usage that is possible with `.set()`.

Answer (score 2):

A simple [example](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/simple_plot.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-simple-plot-py) of its usage:

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Data for plotting
t = np.arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = 1 + np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(t, s)

ax.set(xlabel='time (s)', ylabel='voltage (mV)',
       title='About as simple as it gets, folks')
ax.grid()

fig.savefig("test.png")
plt.show()
```

Beware that the options available to the other two approach you mention will not be available when using [`ax.set()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set), because this is only *"a property batch setter"*, hence only properties of `Axes` will be exposed.

Comment: I'm afraid that your answer doesn't contribute, unless you can give a sound reference/explanation of your last  last statement.  I'm sorry that my question led you  to understand that I don't know how to use `ax.set()` but now I have edited it.

Comment: @gboffi I think that the last sentence in the answer addresses precisely the last sentence in the question: you cannot use e.g. `rotation` etc in `set`. Only `Axes` properties are available through `set()`.

Comment: _"… unless you can give a sound reference/explanation of your last last statement."_

Comment: @gboffi how about the official documentation?

Comment: Give an extract of the official documentation then

Comment: @gboffi That is what I did: "a property batch setter" is the relevant extract of the docs